# Style CSS based on nth term count

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a short css `nth-of-type()` block where I want to style objects based on their n count. I have looked through google but have been unsuccessful in finding an answer. Here is my code:

```
a:nth-of-type(n + 3){
    top: 950px;
}
```

Is it in any way possible to change the `top:` bit depending on the n count, so that it appears something like:

```
a:nth-of-type(n + 3){
    top: 950px * n;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: could you provide the code in which you are using in order to visually see effect? (js fiddle would be great!)

Comment: You could use CSS compilers like LESS or SASS. They allow you to use variables to write your css .

Comment: In pure CSS, the short answer is no. The long answer is unfortunately no you can't (yet). To my knowledge, you'd have to implement this with JavaScript to get the results you're desiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

CSS doesn't work like this, unfortunately.  Despite what it looks like, `n` does not become a variable that you can use within that block of style.  It's used to indicate that you are using the form `(an + b)` to specify a cycle size `a` and a starting counter `b`.  For instance, `a:nth-of-type(2n + 3)` would select every other anchor element starting at the third.

To do something like what you are describing, you would need to use javascript or a CSS precompiler like LESS or SASS.

**Bonus:** In case you're curious, you could do something like this in jQuery to achieve what you are trying to do with pure CSS:

```
$('a').each( function( n, element ) {
    if ( n > 2 ) $(element).css('top',(n*950)+'px');
});
```

Or, if you want to use a preprocessor like SASS, (which would be preferrable to a JS solution for styling) you could do something like this:

```
$max: 100 // or whatever maximum number of elements you need to account for
@for $i from 3 to $max
  a:nth-of-type(#{$i})
    top: #{$i*950}px
```

**Bonus 2:** Here's a rather elegant pure JS solution from David Thomas in the comments:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function (aElem, index) {
    if (index > 2) {
        aElem.style.top = (index * 90) + 'px';
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/23nfskwb/ (note that while a smaller multiplier, `90`, is used instead of `950`, this is just a simple demo, using `950` would be perfectly acceptable)

Comment: how about using jquery to inject css dynamically?

Comment: @jbutler483: Sure, but that's not the same as dynamic CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock: that's true, but this would allow you to do what the OP is asking, is it not?

Comment: The question isn't asking how to do it.  It's asking whether or not it can be done in a similar way with CSS.  Doing this with jQuery would be trivial, but that's not the question.

Comment: @CaseyRule: I call that 'splitting hairs'. Otherwise, the answer would be either a 'Yes' or 'No'.

Comment: The answer is 'No', however it is not appropriate to simply leave a 'Yes' or 'No' as an answer on this site, without explaining your answer.

Comment: @jbutler483: I guess it depends on the person reading/answering the question. For some people, jQuery *never* comes to mind simply because there is no mention of it anywhere in the question, or perhaps it does come to mind but the answerer chooses to stay within the scope of the question. Others may already have a workaround in mind, for any reason (for example, because there are lots of things you can't do with CSS without the help of a script), and will automatically suggest one in their answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: It was more because it seems to be the *only* way to describe what the OP is asking? by saying 'no' when there is *a* way doesn't really help anyone...

Comment: @jbutler483 That's a fair point, and perhaps I was being a little too pedantic initially.  I think I've come up with a good compromise solution by answering the question, but also providing some alternative implementations as an aside at the end.  Does that address your concerns?

Comment: For what it's worth, jQuery isn't (really) required for this, plain JavaScript is perfectly capable (though I've used smaller numbers, `90` instead of `950`): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/23nfskwb/). (Incidentally, is jsFiddle still being a bit weird in with its cursor behaviour, or is it just me?)

Comment: @dDavidThomas: is that where the curser seems to be too far to the left when typing? thought it was just my pc at first. But if JQuery is already in use then it should also be valid

Comment: It is, it really is; I love JS Fiddle (since there's no way to link to snippets in comments) but it's currently a little painful to use. And yes, there's no reason *not* to use jQuery, it's just that there's no need to include it *just* for this use-case. :)

Comment: @David Thomas: I think it's safe to consider "jQuery" to be synonymous with "a script" nowadays :)

Comment: @BoltClock: *sigh* I know; those young kids, these days... ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible with CSS.

The best way to achieve something like this would be to use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, **not** to use JavaScript (or a library like jQuery). This is because styling should be without the need for JavaScript whenever possible due to the fact that it would calculate it after the page is loaded each time instead of doing it on the server side like a preprocessor.

Here I am using SCSS, a more CSS-like variation of SASS, to do what you're trying to do (untested).

```
$n:30; /* The max number of objects (really the max -3 number in your case) */
@for $i from 1 to $n {
  a:nth-of-type(#{$i} + 3) {
    top: 950px * #{$i};
  }
}
```

Comment: There still isn't a way to use n as a variable, so you couldn't do something like `--counter: n` and use that to affect the top declaration.

Comment: That's surprising to me - seems like it takes away most of the use cases